# Add certain inline css to parent div, if child div not contain certain inline css

Tags: jquery, html, css, inline

Based on snippet below, for the current show div, it will insert an inline css 
`display: block` while other div will be `display: none` . All of those div contain the same class `.boxlink`. Their parent div class is `.product-link`.

Now, I've created an if statement where, if `.boxlink` contain an inline css of `display: block`, its parent div will have an inline css `background: #E6DCD0`.

But it's not working. May I know why and how to solve it? Basically, I want the current show `.boxlink` parent div which is  `.product-link` to be `background: #E6DCD0`.

P/S : The if statement is down below inside the jquery snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $boxes = $('.boxlink');
  var $links = $('.product-link');
  var cycle = false;
  var cycle_step = 0;

  $('.productlist .product-link').mouseenter(function() {
    boxActivate(this.id);
    stopCycle();
  });

  $('.productlist .product-link').mouseleave(function() {
    cycle = setTimeout(function(){
        startCycle();
    }, 1000);
  });

  var boxActivate = function(id){
    $boxes.hide().filter('#box' + id).show();
  }
  // cycle - only when mouse is not over links
  var startCycle = function(){
    cycle = setInterval(function(){
        boxActivate($links.get(cycle_step).id);
        cycle_step++;
        if(cycle_step==$links.length) {
            cycle_step=0;
        }
    }, 3000);
  }
  var stopCycle = function(){
    clearInterval(cycle);
  }

  startCycle();

});

$(document).ready(function(){
if ( $('.boxlink').prop('style').display == 'block' ) {
   $('.boxlink').parent().css( "background", "#E6DCD0");
}
   });
```

```css
.product-link {
    float: left;
    width: 128px;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-certified, .product-icon-box-desc-warranty, .product-icon-box-desc-buyback, .product-icon-box-desc-shipping {
    display: none;
    width: 512px;
}

.product-link:hover {
    background: #E6DCD0;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-certified {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-warranty {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -128px;
    background: #fff;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-buyback {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -256px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="productlist">
    <div id="link0" class="product-link">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-ori.png" /> 
       <i>Authenticity & Restoration</i>
     </a>
     <div id="boxlink0" class="product-icon-box-desc-certified boxlink">
     <p class="certified-title">CERTIFIED AUTHENTIC</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Aliquam libero lorem, rutrum vitae dolor quis, pellentesque placerat lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Sed ullamcorper dictum libero eget aliquet. In mauris est, blandit ut aliquam at, tristique ac orci. Quisque mollis, lectus in tempor bibendum, libero dui aliquet odio, vitae dictum arcu elit sit amet eros. Maecenas pellentesque nunc enim, id porta orci pretium vitae. Nam pellentesque sem vitae neque iaculis, vel tincidunt ligula mollis. In fringilla dictum tortor eu accumsan. Donec ac neque et ligula egestas venenatis. Donec malesuada ultricies posuere. Nullam risus nunc, finibus sit amet nisi ac, molestie tempor dui.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="link1" class="product-link">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-waranty.png" /> 
       <i>12 Months Warranty</i>
     </a>
     <div id="boxlink1" class="product-icon-box-desc-warranty boxlink">
     <p class="certified-title">CERTIFIED PRE-OWNED WATCHES WARRANTY</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Donec ac nibh urna. Mauris porta quis lacus id efficitur. Mauris sit amet congue nunc. Nullam tellus lacus, vehicula non viverra id, fringilla eu sapien. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum nulla in ex facilisis blandit non eu risus. Nam imperdiet sed risus fermentum tristique. Integer elementum vitae diam non volutpat. Praesent in mi blandit nunc efficitur elementum. Etiam dapibus dui dui, vitae pretium urna dapibus at.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="link2" class="product-link">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-buyback.png" /> 
       <i>Buy Back / Trade In Guarantee</i>
     </a>
     <div id="boxlink2" class="product-icon-box-desc-buyback boxlink">
     <p class="certified-title">LIFE TIME BUY BACK / TRADE-IN TERMS AND CONDITION</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Phasellus dolor nisi, ullamcorper ac mauris posuere, scelerisque viverra urna. Vivamus eleifend ullamcorper ex condimentum iaculis. Nunc volutpat massa id dui imperdiet interdum. Nullam quis libero sed velit pretium ornare. In vestibulum sollicitudin est, a fermentum libero. Praesent in ultricies libero. Integer eget dignissim diam. Donec volutpat ultrices auctor. Proin euismod magna ut nulla condimentum tempor. Donec at elit magna. Etiam pretium, augue at fringilla porta, neque nibh pulvinar nibh, at posuere ex dui ac enim. Nunc erat nibh, rhoncus non varius et, blandit in purus.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert the line I have suggested in previous answer inside **boxActivate** function. Also, set background: none, before setting the background color to next element.

One more thing you need to do is set background colour on load for the boxlink visible. For that, I have added this line on document.ready:

```
 $('.boxlink:last').parent().css( "background", "#E6DCD0");
```

Since, I could see your **last** `div` was being display on load.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $boxes = $('.boxlink');
  var $links = $('.product-link');
  var cycle = false;
  var cycle_step = 0;

  $('.productlist .product-link').mouseenter(function() {
    boxActivate(this.id);
    stopCycle();
  });

  $('.productlist .product-link').mouseleave(function() {
    cycle = setTimeout(function(){
        startCycle();
    }, 1000);
  });

  var boxActivate = function(id){
    $boxes.hide().filter('#box' + id).show();
     $('.boxlink').parent().css( "background", "none");
     $('.boxlink:visible').parent().css( "background", "#E6DCD0");
  }
  // cycle - only when mouse is not over links
  var startCycle = function(){
    cycle = setInterval(function(){
        boxActivate($links.get(cycle_step).id);
        cycle_step++;
        if(cycle_step==$links.length) {
            cycle_step=0;
        }
    }, 3000);
  }
  var stopCycle = function(){
    clearInterval(cycle);
  }

  startCycle();

});

$(document).ready(function(){
//if ( $('.boxlink').prop('style').display == 'block' ) {
  // $('.boxlink:visible').parent().css( "background", "#E6DCD0");
//}
  $('.boxlink:last').parent().css( "background", "#E6DCD0");
   });
```

```css
.product-link {
    float: left;
    width: 128px;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-certified, .product-icon-box-desc-warranty, .product-icon-box-desc-buyback, .product-icon-box-desc-shipping {
    display: none;
    width: 512px;
}

.product-link:hover {
    background: #E6DCD0;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-certified {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-warranty {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -128px;
    background: #fff;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-buyback {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -256px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="productlist">
    <div id="link0" class="product-link">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-ori.png" /> 
       <i>Authenticity & Restoration</i>
     </a>
     <div id="boxlink0" class="product-icon-box-desc-certified boxlink">
     <p class="certified-title">CERTIFIED AUTHENTIC</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Aliquam libero lorem, rutrum vitae dolor quis, pellentesque placerat lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Sed ullamcorper dictum libero eget aliquet. In mauris est, blandit ut aliquam at, tristique ac orci. Quisque mollis, lectus in tempor bibendum, libero dui aliquet odio, vitae dictum arcu elit sit amet eros. Maecenas pellentesque nunc enim, id porta orci pretium vitae. Nam pellentesque sem vitae neque iaculis, vel tincidunt ligula mollis. In fringilla dictum tortor eu accumsan. Donec ac neque et ligula egestas venenatis. Donec malesuada ultricies posuere. Nullam risus nunc, finibus sit amet nisi ac, molestie tempor dui.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="link1" class="product-link">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-waranty.png" /> 
       <i>12 Months Warranty</i>
     </a>
     <div id="boxlink1" class="product-icon-box-desc-warranty boxlink">
     <p class="certified-title">CERTIFIED PRE-OWNED WATCHES WARRANTY</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Donec ac nibh urna. Mauris porta quis lacus id efficitur. Mauris sit amet congue nunc. Nullam tellus lacus, vehicula non viverra id, fringilla eu sapien. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum nulla in ex facilisis blandit non eu risus. Nam imperdiet sed risus fermentum tristique. Integer elementum vitae diam non volutpat. Praesent in mi blandit nunc efficitur elementum. Etiam dapibus dui dui, vitae pretium urna dapibus at.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="link2" class="product-link">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-buyback.png" /> 
       <i>Buy Back / Trade In Guarantee</i>
     </a>
     <div id="boxlink2" class="product-icon-box-desc-buyback boxlink">
     <p class="certified-title">LIFE TIME BUY BACK / TRADE-IN TERMS AND CONDITION</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Phasellus dolor nisi, ullamcorper ac mauris posuere, scelerisque viverra urna. Vivamus eleifend ullamcorper ex condimentum iaculis. Nunc volutpat massa id dui imperdiet interdum. Nullam quis libero sed velit pretium ornare. In vestibulum sollicitudin est, a fermentum libero. Praesent in ultricies libero. Integer eget dignissim diam. Donec volutpat ultrices auctor. Proin euismod magna ut nulla condimentum tempor. Donec at elit magna. Etiam pretium, augue at fringilla porta, neque nibh pulvinar nibh, at posuere ex dui ac enim. Nunc erat nibh, rhoncus non varius et, blandit in purus.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! geez no idea it needs to set the background to none first. Appreciate your time to solve this.

Comment: background:   none need to be set to remove background color from previously applied background in div.

Answer (score 0):

use `$('.boxlink').is(":visible")` instead of `$('.boxlink').prop('style').display == 'block'`

and add `background` for `$('.boxlink')` not its parent

Comment: The question asks, "Why?", not how to fix it, though fixing it is useful but you don't need to re-post all of it.

Comment: If I add background color to .boxlink, then the background color for .boxlink gonna change. I want to change its parent div.

Answer (score 0):

The css styles in jquery can be accessed using css method as below:

```
if ( $('.boxlink').css('display') == 'block' ) {
   $('.boxlink').parent().css( "background", "#E6DCD0");
}
```

Also, you can also use (":visible") or (":hidden") selector to check if element is visible or not:

```
 if ( !$('.boxlink').is(":hidden") ) {
       $('.boxlink').parent().css( "background", "#E6DCD0");
    }
```

or

```
 if ( $('.boxlink').is(":visible") ) {
       $('.boxlink').parent().css( "background", "#E6DCD0");
 }
```

You are using `prop` method, which is basically used for properties of element for eg. to get or set boolean values like checked, disabled etc. `style` is considered as its attribute and jQuery provides separate set of functions to manipulate styles in DOM. These are style manipulation methods exist in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/.

**Update:**

As per requirement, to change only visible `boxlink` parent background, you can simply write this line:

```
$('.boxlink:visible').parent().css( "background", "#E6DCD0");
```

Comment: The question asks, "Why?", not how to fix it, though fixing it is useful

Comment: @Rob, added explanation

Comment: Actually, I'm looking into fixing it too. btw, your solution makes all the background parent div of .boxlink become #E6DCD0. I just want the current .boxlink parent div only.

Comment: @NazrinNoorzan, I have added an update to answer, according to your requirement.

Comment: @Komal, it's not working. I'm using that code and all .boxlink parent div background changed.

Comment: @NazrinNoorzan, Added another answer with Code snippet.